# Pylint E0401 import error for libraries when running on Gitlab

Tags: python, continuous-integration, gitlab, robotframework, pylint

Pylint is raising import errors when run through Gitlab CI but no such errors are showing up when run locally. All our libraries are entered in our requirements.txt file in the repo. When pylint runs in our CI it lists errors like these:

```
E0401: Unable to import 'robot.libraries.String' (import-error)
E0401: Unable to import 'robot.libraries.BuiltIn' (import-error)
E0401: Unable to import 'robot.api' (import-error)
E0401: Unable to import 'PageObjectLibrary' (import-error)
E0401: Unable to import 'xerox' (import-error)
E0401: Unable to import 'pandas' (import-error)
```

This is how the imports are written in our code:

```
import sys, os, random, string, csv
from robot.libraries.String import String
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn
from robot.api import logger
import time
import datetime
from PageObjectLibrary import PageObject
import xerox
import pandas as pd
```

It looks like any modules that need to be imported are not being detected. Is there some kind of interaction between pylint and requirements.txt?

This is how pylint is run in our yml file:

```
 pylint --output-format=text $FILES | tee ./pylint/pylint.log || pylint-exit $?
```

The $FILES is a list of all changed .py files

pylint version:

```
pylint 2.6.0
astroid 2.4.2
Python 3.9.1 (default, Jan 18 2021, 15:07:40)
[Clang 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.28)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Pylint need to be able to import the package in order to analyze it. The error you have, probably means it can import them locally but not on the continuous integration. Check that you're on the same environnement you installed the requirements on, and compare to your local env by launching `pip freeze` on both env.